# using classes to create a coin toss program

Tags: c++

having trouble figuring out the constructors  the code in the main() is supposed to test the class so i can go on to the rest of the program.
this is the instructions 
Constructors

This class has two constructors. The default constructor (the one that takes no arguments) should initialize the value of the coin to a penny (0.01) and the side should be initialized by calling the toss() method that is described below.

The other constructor takes 1 argument: a double that holds the initial value for the coin. The passed in argument should be used to initialize the value of the coin. No error checking is required. The side should be initialized by calling the toss() method that is described below.

**this is the code**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;



//Put the Coin class definition after this line

class Coin
{
public:
  Coin()
  {
  value = 0.01;
  toss();

  }

  Coin(double )
  {
  toss();




  }

  void toss();

  int getSide();
  double getValue();

private:
  double value; 
  char side[6];
};










int main()
{
//Set the random number generator and the formatting for the output

srand( 1 );

cout << fixed << setprecision(2);


//Create objects using the two constructors

Coin coin1;
Coin coin2( 0.25 );
Coin coin3( 0.10 );

//Test 1: the getSide method

cout << "Test 1: use the getSide method on all of the objects" << endl <<     endl
     << "coin1 has " << ( (coin1.getSide() == 1)? "heads" : "tails" ) << " up" << endl
 << "coin2 has " << ( (coin2.getSide() == 1)? "heads" : "tails" ) << " up" << endl
     << "coin3 has " << ( (coin3.getSide() == 1)? "heads" : "tails" ) << " up" << endl;

//Test 2: the getValue method

cout << endl << endl
     << "Test 2: use the getValue method on all of the objects" << endl << endl
     << "coin1 has the value $" << coin1.getValue() << endl
     << "coin2 has the value $" << coin2.getValue() << endl
     << "coin3 has the value $" << coin3.getValue() << endl;

//Test 3: the toss method

cout << endl << endl
     << "Test 3: use the toss method 5 times on all of the objects" << endl << endl;

cout << "coin1       coin2       coin3" << endl
     << "-----------------------------" << endl;

for( int cnt = 1; cnt <= 5; cnt++ )
  {
  coin1.toss();
  cout << ( (coin1.getSide() == 1)? "heads" : "tails" );

  coin2.toss();
  cout << ( (coin2.getSide() == 1)? "       heads" : "       tails" );

  coin3.toss();
  cout << ( (coin3.getSide() == 1)? "       heads" : "       tails" ) << endl;
  }

return 0;
}

//Code the constructors and methods for the Coin class after this line


 void Coin::toss()
    {


    int num = rand() % 2+ 1;
    if (num == 1)
    {

       strcpy(side,"heads");
     }
       else 
       {

           strcpy(side,"tails");
       }
   }
 int Coin::getSide()
    {
      if (side=="heads")
       {
        return 1;

       }
       else 
       {
        return 2;
       }

    }

 double Coin::getValue()
    {
     return value;


    }
```

Comment: Fyi, you `toss()` your `Coin` in the default constructor, but not in the single-param constructor. As `toss()` is where you populate `side[]`, the parameterized constructor version leaves you toting around an indeterminate `side[]`. Either call `toss()` from both or provide a default value (preferably in both).

Comment: thanks i put toss() in the single param constructor for some reason when i run all that comes up is tails is there a problem with toss() ?

Comment: No, it is a problem with `side == "heads"` You don't compare `char*` strings that way. Were `side` a `std::string` that would work (but other parts of your code would need changing). I wouldn't do that anyway. I would have a enum that held 0 for heads, 1 for tails, and a static class char array for display, `static const char *faces[] = {"heads", "tails"};` With that, you would simply display `faces[side]` to get the text version for display. It would also make your `toss()` function and `getSide()` functions *trivial*.

Comment: `srand( 1 );` is pointless and redundant. According to the C standard (C11 §7.22.2.2/2), "If `rand` is called before any calls to `srand` have been made, the same sequence shall be generated as when srand is first called with a seed value of 1."

Comment: it may because the teacher is having us do it a certain way it says this in the instructions               Note: The integer value is being returned because we don't know how to return a character array at this point in the class (and it won't be taught until the CSCI 241 class).

Comment: There are a lot of red flags here. You might consider a different approach from relying on incompetent teachers, or a program which takes multiple semesters before you can do anything useful at all.

Comment: please help  or point me in the right direction somebody

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally figured it out thanks anyone who gave an effort!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;



//Put the Coin class definition after this line

class Coin
{
public:
  Coin();
  Coin(double );
  void toss();

  int getSide();
  double getValue();

 private:
double value;   
char side[6];
};

int main()
{
//Set the random number generator and the formatting for the output

srand(  time(NULL) );

cout << fixed << setprecision(2);


  //Create objects using the two constructors

Coin coin1;
Coin coin2( 0.25 );
Coin coin3( 0.10 );


double balance;

  while (balance < 1.00)

{
cout << "current Balance: "<<balance<<endl;

coin1.toss();
cout<< "Nickel: "<< ( (coin1.getSide() == 1)? "heads" : "tails" )<<endl;
 if (coin1.getSide()==1)
    {
    balance +=coin1.getValue();

    }

coin3.toss();
cout<< "Dime: " << ( (coin3.getSide() == 1)? "heads" : "tails" )<<endl;
if (coin3.getSide()==1)
    {
    balance +=coin3.getValue();

    }
coin2.toss();
cout<< "Quarter: " << ( (coin2.getSide() == 1)? "heads" : "tails" )<<endl;
if (coin2.getSide()==1)
    {
    balance +=coin2.getValue();

    }
cout << "-----------------------------" <<endl
<< "your current balance is $"<< balance <<endl
<< endl;



}


cout<< "The final balance is "<< balance<<" Congrats! You won!"<<endl;


return 0;


 }

  //Code the constructors and methods for the Coin class after this line

   void Coin::toss()

     {

int num = rand() % 2+ 1;
if (num == 1)
{

   strcpy(side,"heads");
 }
   else 
   {

       strcpy(side,"tails");
   }
  }
  int Coin::getSide()
{

if (strcmp(side,"heads")==true)
{
return 1;
}
else
return 2;
}


double Coin::getValue()
    {
     return value;


}

Coin::Coin()
{
  value = 0.05;
  toss();

 }

Coin::Coin(double newValue)
{
 value = newValue;



}
```